# Javascript stops when searching for string in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wrote a script to search for a String in innerHTML and clicks the button when the string has the correct value.

Everything is ok when i am searchin for exampe for "313". 
The script reloads when nothing ist found and clicks my button when innerHTML matches 313.

Here the problem:

When i am trying to compare innerHTML with "35,00 €" the script reloads fine when nothing is found.
But when for example "60,00 €" is found the script stops. No reload of the page follows.

Can somebody tell me why????

Here my script:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var ClickID, IDString, anfang, clickstring, element, ende, i, zeile, zeilen;
  zeilen = document.getElementsByClassName('content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear');
  i = 0;
  while (i < zeilen.length) {
    zeile = zeilen[i];
    if (zeile.children[3].children[0].innerHTML == "35,00 €") {
      IDString = zeile.children[0].children[0].id;
      ClickID = IDString.substr(42, 5);
      anfang = 'ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_';
      ende = '_LinkButton1';
      clickstring = anfang + ClickID + ende;
      element = document.getElementById(clickstring);
      element.click();
      return;
    }
    i++;
}
  location.reload();
  
})();
```

And here is the html it runs on:

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="rows" id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>   
                                   <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label1">101</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label2">16</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label3">21</span>
                                         </span>
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label4">70,00 €</span>
                                         </span>
                                    </p>                     
                                        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
                                            <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl03$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                <hr />
                            </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>   
                                   <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label1">107</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label2">14</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label3">23</span>
                                         </span>
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label4">70,00 €</span>
                                         </span>
                                    </p>                     
                                        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
                                            <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl04$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                <hr />
                            </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>   
                                   <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label1">326</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label2">6</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label3">16</span>
                                         </span>
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label4">60,00 €</span>
                                         </span>
                                    </p>                     
                                        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
                                            <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl05$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                <hr />
                            </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>   
                                   <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label1">313</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label2">18</span>
                                         </span>
                                        <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label3">18</span>
                                         </span>
                                         <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label4">35,00 €</span>
                                         </span>
                                    </p>                     
                                        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
                                            <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl06$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                <hr />
                            </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div> 
           </div>
```

And here is what the Console says:

(unknown) ERROR: Execution of script 'Zweitmarkt_Preis_test' failed! Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: could you please add the HTML also? Will help us to find the error.

Comment: `return` returns from the function. `break` gets you out of the while loop.

Comment: break also stops reloading

Comment: I don't understand your use case ... You are talking about searching for different search strings, but your code only shows "35,00 €". Do you mean you tried the same script with different search strings and "313" and "35,00 €" worked as expected, but "60,00 €" doesn't?

Comment: You cannot use `getElementsByClassName` for multiple class names in one string. Try to use `querySelectorAll` with commas between the class names and `.` (dots) in front of them `querySelectorAll(".content-card-entry,.fcb-row,.fcb-clear")`

Comment: If you only want to match elements with all those classes, you should leave out the commas and append the class names (with the dots) to each other

Comment: there are several td's on that page.

Comment: and when the innerHTML of child matches "35,00 €" the button has to be clicked. It works perfectly when i am searching for a string like "313" in another child

Comment: @DadaRada please copy your entire [table int his page](https://jsfiddle.net/) I need to know the structure of the valid and the invalid `td` ok??

Comment: Done, posted it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix your code. This a working version.

Just remove the comment of the line

```
 //element.click();
```

Ok no how it works?

1. First, we search for all the elements that has these three classes `v.content-card-entry.fcb-row.fcb-clear` as shown this line:

   ```
   rows = document.querySelectorAll('.content-card-entry.fcb-row.fcb-clear');
   ```
2. Then we search for the elements that has a parent `span` and are `span`. This replaced your `children` implementation with:

   ```
   row.querySelectorAll('span > span');
   ```
3. Now we can get the id of this label. Remember according to your HTML you will find 4 kinds of labels and the `Label4` is the one that contains the price. Then you verify that it has an innerHTML value and done.

   ```
   var IDString = label.id;
       if (IDString.includes("Label4")) {
       if (label.innerHTML == amount) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

You can replace the variable `amount = '60,00 €';` with any other value.

Viel Glück.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var ClickID, IDString, anfang, clickstring, ende, amount, rows;
  anfang = 'ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_';
  ende = '_LinkButton1';
  amount = '60,00 €';
  
  rows = document.querySelectorAll('.content-card-entry.fcb-row.fcb-clear');
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var labels = row.querySelectorAll('span > span');
    labels.forEach(function(label) {
      var IDString = label.id;
      if (IDString.includes("Label4")) {
        if (label.innerHTML == amount) {
          ClickID = IDString.substr(42, 5);
          clickstring = anfang + ClickID + ende;        
          var element = document.getElementById(clickstring);
          console.log('Click on: ' + clickstring);
          //element.click();
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  });
 location.reload();
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="rows" id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label1">101</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label2">16</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label3">21</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label4">70,00 €</span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl03$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
        </p>
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label1">107</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label2">14</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label3">23</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_Label4">70,00 €</span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl04_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl04$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
        </p>
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label1">326</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label2">6</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label3">16</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_Label4">60,00 €</span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl05_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl05$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
        </p>
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label1">313</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label2">18</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label3">18</span>
          </span>
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_Label4">35,00 €</span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
          <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl06_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl06$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
        </p>
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the use of `return` gets you our of the function and the reload doesn't get executed. 
use `break` to get out of the while loop

there is a `<p>` tag which matches the `zeilen` class criteria. the p doesnt not have 4 children and hence the script throws error.

https://jsfiddle.net/zw2x6ur2/

Comment: thanks... i will try with break and tell if it works

Comment: break also stops reloading

Comment: Yes, i posted HTML in an answer

Comment: it works with `break` for me. there is an error in your code which exits the script.

Comment: Yes and i am still searching for that error... it has to do with "35,00 €" string, because with strings without blanks or, or € the script works

Comment: @DadaRada seriously? i gave the same answer and not even an upote??

Comment: i am still reading, thinking and trying to understand what you all said. Sorry, i am very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns two paragraphs, however, only the first has DOM children. Therefore your script will error when it processes the second paragraph. One workaround is to check if the children exist in the first place:

```
if (zeile.children[3] && zeile.children[3].children[0].innerHTML == "35,00 €") {
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var ClickID, IDString, anfang, clickstring, element, ende, i, zeile, zeilen;
  zeilen = document.getElementsByClassName('content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear');
  i = 0;
  while (i < zeilen.length) {
    zeile = zeilen[i];    
    if (zeile.children[3] && zeile.children[3].children[0].innerHTML == "35,00 €") {
      IDString = zeile.children[0].children[0].id;
      ClickID = IDString.substr(42, 5);
      anfang = 'ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_';
      ende = '_LinkButton1';
      clickstring = anfang + ClickID + ende;
      element = document.getElementById(clickstring);
      element.click();
      return;
    }
    i++;
}
  //location.reload();
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P1" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear">
    <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label1">101</span>
    </span>
    <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label2">16</span>
    </span>
    <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label3">21</span>
    </span>
    <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-3 fcb-gr-3@small">
                                            <span id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_Label4">70,00 €</span>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_P5" class="content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear" style="text-align:right;">
    <span class="content-card-entry-value fcb-gr-12 fcb-gr-12@small">
                                                <a id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl03_LinkButton1" class="button small cart-buttons-second-button" Autopostback="false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentMiddle$TicketList1$GridView1$ctl03$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">In den&nbsp;Warenkorb</a>
                                            </span>
  </p>
  <hr />
</td>
```